# Traversing travel time in Neo4j graph

Tags: time, neo4j, graph-traversal

I have a graph in NEO4j and I get a traversal time (t1) between source node and target node when I post a REST request to neo4j server, but when I interchanged my nodes then I get different traversal time (t2) between target node and source node, in spite of the same number of edges and nodes in between them.

For more clarification, suppose my graph is like Node1 -> Node 2 - > Node 3 . I'm getting a traversal time T1 for a path between Node1(Source) and Node3(Target) and when I find the path between Node3(Source) and Node1(Target) I get traversal time T2. Ideally, T1 and T2 should be equal but I get different values for them. What is the reason of getting different traversal time?

I even tried to post the same request for Source to Target and I get different traversal time for every request.

When I post a request I get a JSON string, which has edges. I queried the distance between "sourceNodeId": 7091 and  "targetNodeId": 343643.

```
"edges": [
        {
            "sourceNodeId": 7091,
            "id": 494470,
            "type": "test",
            "targetNodeId": 80985
        },
        {
            "sourceNodeId": 73698,
            "id": 1316749,
            "type": "test",
            "targetNodeId": 80985
        },
        {
            "sourceNodeId": 73698,
            "id": 1317536,
            "type": "test",
            "targetNodeId": 343643
        }
    ]
```

Response Time for this request is 650 milliseconds.

When I query the distance between "sourceNodeId": 343643 and  "targetNodeId": 7091,  I get same edges, but response Time for this request is 900 milliseconds

```
"edges": [
        {
            "sourceNodeId": 7091,
            "id": 494470,
            "type": "test",
            "targetNodeId": 80985
        },
        {
            "sourceNodeId": 73698,
            "id": 1316749,
            "type": "test",
            "targetNodeId": 80985
        },
        {
            "sourceNodeId": 73698,
            "id": 1317536,
            "type": "test",
            "targetNodeId": 343643
        }
    ]
```

Comment: Can you share the response in order to see exactly what you mean with traversal time ? If there's only one path between the nodes and you can reach both starting points in the same amount of time there should not be a difference but there's quite a few things that can influence execution time.

Comment: @TomGeudens I have edited my question

Comment: Just ruling out the obvious here. You are the traversing with start and end node determined by the same - presumably indexed - property (with a different value) ? Also, when you do a mix of the traversals several times, both the execution times and the difference stays in the same order of magnitude ?

Comment: Value is always same and the response time is random no fix order sometime it is less and other time it more in magnitude

Comment: What I would do is try the same thing as a Cypher MATCH statement in the Neo4j browser. There you will be able to see how much time is actually spend in execution and how much in streaming the data. The execution time there should be equal. My guess would be that you're probably seeing variations in the serving of the data (and/or caching).